# Using UpdateModelMixin update() to update record

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

How can I perform a partial update within `list()`? I am trying to update the balance value in a `Wallet` record

```
class WalletListCreateAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView, mixins.UpdateModelMixin):
    queryset = Wallet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WalletSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        current_user = request.user
        wallets = Wallet.objects.filter(user=current_user)
        balances = get_wallet_balances([wallet.address for wallet in wallets])
        for wallet in wallets:
            # Update wallet balance based on address
            balance = balances[wallet.address]
            
        return super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to create a `put()` function inside your view, while inheriting `GenericAPIView` and `UpdateModelMixin`

```
class MyView(GenericAPIView, UpdateModelMixin):

    serializer_class = MySerializer
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'id'

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

---

You should create your serializer to contain only the fields you want to update

serializers.py:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ["field_1", "field_2", "field_3"]
```

Take into consideration that any field that has `null=False` in the model will be required and not optional

You can dodge this by adding

```
extra_kwargs = {"field_x": {"required": False}}
```

in your `Meta` class